# Return a word after another word in an excel file

Tags: excel, lookup

I have a file that has several entries that do not match the expected output. I want to search for the string "Warning" then have excel move 2 rows up and return the information in that cell to another column.
This may be confusing. 
Thanks for any help. I know they'll be questions because I probably haven't explained this adequately.

Comment: Please show an example,expected output and what you have tried. It will help you get answers. In the mean time you can look at: https://www.excel-exercise.com/create-an-offset-vlookup/ this could also easily be done using VBA

Comment: How do I add the excel sheet?

Comment: Edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)